# Rails 4 nested strong parameters throwing unpermited parameters error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I've been at this for hours now but can't figure it out:

Trying to create a new address in the new organisation form. An address can be created for an organisation, company or employee. I want the Address_id relevant to the Orgainsation/Company/Employee to be stored in their database record but can't get strong_parameters to work properly.

> **models/organisation.rb**

```
class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

> **models/address.rb**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :organisations
    has_many :companies
    has_many :employees
end
```

> **views/organisations/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@organisation) do |f| %>
  <% if @organisation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@organisation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this organisation from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @organisation.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>

<%= f.fields_for @address do |t| %> 
  <div>
    <%= t.label :Line_1 %><br />
    <%= t.text_field :line1 %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= t.label :Line_2 %><br />
    <%= t.text_field :line2 %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= t.label :Line_3 %><br />
    <%= t.text_field :line3 %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= t.label :Line_4 %><br />
    <%= t.text_field :line4 %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= t.label :Postcode %><br />
    <%= t.text_field :postcode %>
  </div>     
  <div>
    <%= t.label :Country %><br />
    <%= t.text_field :country %>
  </div>                            
<% end %>

 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :phone %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :phone %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

> **controllers/organisations_controller.rb**

```
class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
 espond_to :html, :json
 before_action :set_organisation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def new
  @organisation = Organisation.new
  @address = Address.new
  respond_with(@organisation)
 end


 def create
  puts "Start of debug"
  puts organisation_params[:address_attributes]
  puts "End of debug"
  @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)
  @address = Address.new(organisation_params[:address_attributes])
  @address.save
  @organisation.address = @address.id
  @organisation.save
  respond_with(@organisation)
 end

 private
 def set_organisation
  @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id])
 end

 def organisation_params
   params.require(:organisation).permit(:name, :phone, :creator, :contact, :renewal, :approved, :balance, address_attributes:[:line1, :line2, :line3, :line4, :postcode, :country, :organisation_id])
 end
end
```

But I keep getting the following **error**:

```
Started POST "/organisations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-11 23:40:54 +0000
Processing by OrganisationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T2344536dhfjkhkj3eb5g43glwy547fy5p2nbydddfr=", "organisation"=>{"name"=>"The company", "address"=>{"line1"=>"1 The Road", "line2"=>"", "line3"=>"", "line4"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "country"=>"Ireland"}, "phone"=>"01111111"}, "commit"=>"Create Organisation"}
Start of debug
Unpermitted parameters: address

End of debug
Unpermitted parameters: address
Unpermitted parameters: address
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-12-11 23:40:54.404236"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-11 23:40:54.404236"]]
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "line1" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2014-12-11 23:40:54.404236, 2014-12-11 23:40:54.404236).
: INSERT INTO "addresses" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "line1" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2014-12-11 23:40:54.404236, 2014-12-11 23:40:54.404236).
: INSERT INTO "addresses" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"):
  app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

It looks to me that the address is not getting created because it doesn't have access to the  address attributes which are passed but are 'unpermitted parameters'. Even though I include it in the organisation_params.permit statement????

Am I doing something wrong here?

> **Edit 1**

As per hkumar's suggestion I've edited the `views/organisations/_form.html.erb` file to now say `<%= f.fields_for "#{@address}_attributes" do |t| %>`

But the error now looks like:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T2344536dhfjkhkj3eb5g43glwy547fy5p2nbydddfr=", "organisation"=>{"name"=>"The company", "#<Address:0x00000003aa2690>_attributes"=>{"line1"=>"The Road", "line2"=>"", "line3"=>"", "line4"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "country"=>"Ireland"}, "phone"=>"01111111"}, "commit"=>"Create Organisation"}
Start of debug
Unpermitted parameters: #<Address:0x00000003aa2690>_attributes

End of debug
```

> **Edit 2**

Followed Paul Richter's advice and now the error is:

```
Started POST "/organisations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-12 01:35:13 +0000
Processing by OrganisationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T2344536dhfjkhkj3eb5g43glwy547fy5p2nbydddfr=", "organisation"=>{"name"=>"The company", "address_attributes"=>{"line1"=>"The road", "line2"=>"", "line3"=>"", "line4"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "country"=>"Ireland"}, "phone"=>"01111111"}, "commit"=>"Create Organisation"}
Start of debug
{"name"=>"The company", "phone"=>"01111111", "address_attributes"=>{"line1"=>"The road", "line2"=>"", "line3"=>"", "line4"=>"", "postcode"=>"", "country"=>"Ireland"}}
End of debug
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "addresses" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-12-12 01:35:14.196724"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-12 01:35:14.196724"]]
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "line1" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (46, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2014-12-12 01:35:14.196724, 2014-12-12 01:35:14.196724).
: INSERT INTO "addresses" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 57ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "line1" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (46, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2014-12-12 01:35:14.196724, 2014-12-12 01:35:14.196724).
: INSERT INTO "addresses" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"):
  app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:29:in `create'
```

> **Final edit**

Thanks to Paul Richter, the following code now works (for anyone who stumbles across it):

> **controllers/organisations_controller.rb**

```
class OrganisationsController < ApplicationController
 espond_to :html, :json
 before_action :set_organisation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def new
    @organisation = Organisation.new
    @organisation.build_address
 end


 def create
  @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)
  @organisation.save
  respond_with(@organisation)
 end

 private
 def set_organisation
  @organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id])
 end

 def organisation_params
   params.require(:organisation).permit(:name, :phone, :creator, :contact, :renewal, :approved, :balance, address_attributes:[:line1, :line2, :line3, :line4, :postcode, :country, :organisation_id])
 end
end
```

Comment: Is it because in your in #organisation_params it's permitting  address_attributes:[ without a space between : and [?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue relates to this line in the form:

```
f.fields_for @address do |t|
```

And this line in the controller (showing the full method so we are all on the same page):

```
def new
  @organisation = Organisation.new
  @address = Address.new  # This line, specifically
  respond_with(@organisation)
end
```

The problem is that you're creating separate `Address` and `Organization` objects as though they are separate independent entities, but since `Address` `belongs_to` `Organization` (according to your model), `Address` is actually dependent on the parent `Organization`, and therefore should be associated properly.

Instead, you would want to do this:

```
def new
  @organisation = Organisation.new
  @organization.build_address
 ...
```

This will set up a new `Address` object which is associated with its parent `Organization`.

Then in the form, change the `fields_for` line to this:

```
f.fields_for :address do |t|
```

This will call the `address` method of the `@organization` object, and [insert rails magic] the naming convention for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` will be used instead.

So in short, the reason you were seeing the error is because, while you had indeed set up the strong parameters correctly, the fact that a separate, disconnected `Address` object was being passed to `f.fields_for` prevented the form fields from being named correctly.

**Edit**

Now that the form is set up properly, change the `create` method to look like this:

```
def create
  @organisation = Organisation.new(organisation_params)
  @organisation.save
  respond_with(@organisation)
end
```

In the comments below, you were mentioning *how to get the id of the address I'm creating and store it on the organisation*. To be clear, there is no `id` of the address at this point, but because you've set up the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` line in the `Organization` model, Rails will create a new `Address` object already associated to the `Organization` by using the `address_attributes` parameters in the `organization_params` hash you passed in.

This one line (`Organisation.new(organisation_params)`) creates the whole structure for you, so long as the parameters match the expected naming convention, which they now should.

Comment: I've changed everything and it's still not working. Is it because my address doesn't in fact belong to the organisation. Have I set the address model up wrong? I did like that as I'm not keeping the organisations id in the address model. I'm instead keeping the address id in the organisation model.

Comment: @AlD No, from the sounds of it the model associations are set up correctly. Define "not working"; what is the form doing right now after the change?

Comment: @AlD Ah, well that's a completely separate problem. You can see that the parameters submitted are named correctly now. The problem you've having is in the actual error message (it says: *null value in column "line1" violates not-null constraint*). You've probably got a not-null constraint on that column, and you're passing a null value.

Comment: I do indeed. I'm stumped on how to get the id of the address I'm creating and store it on the organisation. It's 2am here though so I think it's enough for tonight. Tomorrow's a new day. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AlD Ah ok, I see. I neglected to look closely at your `create` method. I will post an update in a moment.

Comment: Witchcraft I tells ya! Thanks so much Paul. Working perfectly now

Comment: @AlD Sorcery! Heretics! Seriously though, Rails has a lot of "magic", and if you make sure to do things the way Rails expects (and with the framework's flexibility, this is usually a pretty easy task in 99% - 100% of cases), life, and your code, will be so much easier to manage and work with. That's why the other answer wasn't a great idea, because even if it had worked, it was merely treating the symptom, and not the "disease".